# In the parallel universe, is there also a parallel doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

I cant remember if it's mentioned in The show, But in The parallel universe where Ten leaves Rose, is there another Doctor? Since there is a Torchwood, and it was built because of The doctor..

Answer (score 1):

In parallel universe, lots of things are different like Rose's father being alive and non-existence of Rose. So, another set of events can lead to formation of Torchwood.

In reality, there's no "original" Doctor in the parallel universe. I concluded this because Rose spent lots of time finding Doctor, but she didn't find him in there. Also, when reality was threatened by Davros and Daleks (Episode: The Journey's End), no Doctor from parallel universe came to save the reality. At that point, The Doctor put meta-crisis Doctor (half Time Lord, half Human) in the parallel universe which is the only Doctor in there at this time.

Comment: It's also possible that the Doctor was simply dead. We know from "Turn Left" that the Doctor would have died without Donna; it could have been the same with any other missing companion, including Rose.